# Vaadin RichTextArea stripping code from image tag

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

For whatever reason when I `setValue(value)` with the following code:

```
<img src=""/>
```

the `getValue()` then results in:

```
<img src="">
```

This is fine for rendering html but I need to pass the resulting html as xml to generate a PDF and it fails as this is not legal xml code, it needs the closing backslash. Is there any reason it's stripping the backslash? Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I cannot find `RichTextEditor` as a Vaadin component. Google keeps me redirecting to [`RichTextArea`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-richtextarea.html). If you are using other component, can you provide link to it?

Comment: @Shirkam You are right, that's a typo on my part. Sorry about that. Yes RichTextArea.

Comment: could it perhaps be the document type of the page where you're including this? Perhaps you need to define it as XHTML in order to get wellformed XML? see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp